# ASP.NET / Sharepoint - Checkbox.CheckChanged event fires same Event of other (same) control from bevore

Tags: asp.net, events, sharepoint, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I'm working on a Webpart for SharePoint with ASP.NET

On every click my page will be reloaded and I add a List of Checkboxes with different ID's in two tables and a event to handle the CheckedChanged Event (all the same).

In Addition the autopostback is set to true.

When I run and click my first checkbox every thinks work fine.
By clicking the next checkbox in the same table, I get in my eventReceiver 2! Events - first, the right one and after that the checkbox was clicked before.

As many boxes I click, as many checkboxes fire their Event (when used before).

Only difference is between the 2 Tables. Here clicking in first table all is ok, clicking in second table all ok... after that each table has the same effect. Click in first table again, I get 2 Events to handle, click in the second one these 2 to handle.

I have no idea what's going wrong.

Here's some code

```
CheckBox eMailNotifikation = new CheckBox() { TextAlign = TextAlign.Right };
eMailNotifikation.ID = #anCounter + "_" + #anName + "_" + #anothername + "_" + "mail_checkbox";
eMailNotifikation.AutoPostBack = true;          
eMailNotifikation.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(eMailNotifikation_CheckedChanged);
eMailNotifikation.Checked = #setInitialValue;
//Add Event
eMailNotifikation.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(eMailNotifikation_CheckedChanged);
cell.Controls.Add(eMailNotifikation);
```

that's it for creation

here's my receiver:

`void eMailNotifikation_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBox eMailNotification = (sender as CheckBox);
    //Do some... calling a Webservice
    eRoomWebservice.DoMyTasl(<params>);

    }`

the tables are only build with new... and ID.. nothing Special

EDIT::::
I've build the code in easy ASP.NET and there it is working, maybe this is a SharePoint Issue
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Table test = new Table();
            test.ID = "test1";

```
        TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
        thc.Text = "Checkboxes";

        thr.Controls.Add(thc);
        test.Controls.Add(thr);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow();            

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
            chb.ID = "Some_" + i;
            chb.AutoPostBack = true;
            chb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(TestEH);

            tc.Controls.Add(chb);
            tr.Controls.Add(tc); 
        }


        test.Controls.Add(tr);
        root.Controls.Add(test);
    }

    void TestEH(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CheckBox chbx = sender as CheckBox;
        string text = chbx.ID;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out wha'ts the Problem on my posted issue.

Content of the attribute ID="" was too Long, after shrinking the IDName it was working again.

Strange but it was the solution,
Remember: Watch out how Long Content of the Attribute ID is, there must be a Limit somewhere